# "For Each" loop : Application Freeze in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, foreach

I am using the following code to get the size of files inside a directory 
and put it in `Label1`:

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles( _
   "\windows",Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly,_
   "*.*")
        Dim filesizelabel As System.IO.FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(foundFile)
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + filesizelabel.Length
    Next
```

The problem is that i have more than 50 for each loops (a system cleaning app).

When I run the loops my app freezes until the loops finish, even if I run one loop.

Is there a solution to make it show the name of the current file? I tried this as well, but it also froze my application:

```
label2.text = foundfile
```

The application does not respond to any click, until it finishes the loops.  It shows the size in `Label1` and the last scanned file in `Label2`.  This also freezes the application:

```
system.threading.thread.sleep(100)
```

**Is there any alternative to foreach or a solution to fix this issue?**

Comment: I am not familiar with vb.net syntax but you probably want to start the loop on a new thread rather than UI thread so it doesn't block.

Comment: how can i do that (in a class or a module...)

Comment: Two things com into my mind: 1. The good old `BackgroundWorker`. 2. The new `Async` / `Await` keywords. Google for these terms.

Comment: Hmm... i saw the 'BackgroundWorker' in the first day of me using vb.net but i've never thought it can do that. Thnx

Comment: Look like i have some problems with backgroundworker and threading...

Comment: i cannot **foundfile**  to a listview from background worker

Comment: can anyone help please

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick example using Async/Await with a Button Click() Handler:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Enabled = False

    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       ' this runs in a different thread without blocking the GUI:
                       For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
                                     "\windows", Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.*")
                           Dim filesizelabel As System.IO.FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(foundFile)

                           ' when you need to update the GUI:
                           Me.Invoke(Sub()
                                         ' ... do it in here ...

                                         Label1.Text = Label1.Text + filesizelabel.Length

                                     End Sub)
                       Next
                   End Sub)

    Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

For VB.Net 2010, try this instead:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Dim T As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Worker)
    T.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Worker()
    ' this runs in a different thread without blocking the GUI:
    For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
                  "\windows", Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.*")
        Dim filesizelabel As System.IO.FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(foundFile)

        ' when you need to update the GUI:
        Me.Invoke(Sub()
                      ' ... do it in here ...

                      Label1.Text = Label1.Text + filesizelabel.Length

                  End Sub)
    Next

    Me.Invoke(Sub()
                  Button1.Enabled = True
              End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: look like you code is geat but it's not working. i get a lot of **end of statment expected** and **Declaration Expected**

Comment: What version .Net are you using?

Comment: Vb.Net 2010 (.Net 4.0)

Answer (score 1):

This is a prime candidate for a [background worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx).

Have a read about how they work, but at a high level the task is run in another thread with some events that you access in your main UI thread.

```
    Private bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker

    Private Sub buttonStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        If Not bw.IsBusy = True Then
            ' this will start the work
            bw.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub buttonCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        If bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True Then
            ' this will allow the user to cancel the work part way through
            bw.CancelAsync()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)    
        ' your slow code goes here
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        ' you can update the UI here to show progress
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        ' your 'I've finished notification' code goes here 
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Derek has put a bad code, it's not working and Idle mind code does not work on .NET 2.0

Dereks approach is working if code is complete, as below:

```
Private bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker
Private Sub app_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
        AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted
..
End sub
Private Sub Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn.Click
        If Not bw.IsBusy = True Then
            ' this will start the work
            bw.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
End Sub
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
'your work to not freeze form
end sub
Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        ' you can update the UI here to show progress
End Sub
Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        ' your 'I've finished notification' code goes here 
End Sub
```